# Return string based on values within the string without truncating

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column containing values like this, example:

Farari - Made in 2013

Mercedes - Made in 2012

Jaguar - Made in 1978

I want to return the car with the highest or recent make year:

Something like this will give me the year but obviously will truncate the rest of the string:

```
SELECT
MAX(RIGHT(CarProfile, 4)) 
FROM mySchema.Car;
```

How do I get the highest year but maintain the full string?

In this case: *Farari - Made in 2013*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Car
WHERE   RIGHT(CarProfile, 4) =
        (SELECT MAX(RIGHT(CarProfile, 4)) 
        FROM Car)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd2ec/1)

You should normalize your table properly. My ssugested schema would be adding a column for a year and have index it so that it would have great query performance .

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2efe/1)

Comment: Very true, That's what I am trying to do, was handed down this:

Comment: the best thing about thins query is that it handles `ties`. this will retrieve all records having the latest year.

Comment: Thanks for the tremendous effort, especially with the Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  top 1 *
FROM    Car order by RIGHT(CarProfile, 4)*1 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql below for reference:

```
select CarProfile
  from FROM mySchema.Car
 where substr(CarProfile, CarProfile.length - 4, CarProfile.length) =
        SELECT MAX(RIGHT(CarProfile, 4)) FROM mySchema.Car;
```

Comment: Hello: Sunyen, is this TSQL or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the  'made in' when you print it out, not stored in the database. So instead your table will be:

```
CarProfile | Year
---------------
Ferrari | 2013
Mercedes | 2012
Jaguar | 1978
```

And your 'made in' will either be retrieved via the query like so:

```
SELECT  CarProfile, ' - made in', year
FROM    Car
HAVING  year = MAX(year)
```

Or you can just write it when it is displayed (for example php):

```
<?php echo $CarProfile . " - made in " $year;?>
```

It will make your table much more compact and friendly